# What's this notation for marking up pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, pronunciation-respelling

What's this notation for marking up pronunciation?

> analgesic: ann-ull-JEE-zick

What's a good introductory article or book to learn it?

Comment: It's not a system ... there is no systematic way of getting the mark-up from the pronunciation or vice versa.

Comment: You mean people working in dictionary publishing companies use pronunciation respellings following no protocol whatsoever?  I can't believe you.

Comment: No, I mean there is no agreed-upon standard. Every pronunciation re-speller uses a different system of pronunciation respelling.  That's why you should use IPA. If you don't believe me, look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English). For example, if I'm reading it right, Wikipedia and the BBC would respell Utah as YOO-taa and YEW-tah.

Comment: As long as there is some agreed-upon standard within some of the individual institutions.  It's totally fine that there is not a universal standard.  Human race suffer a lot from the absence of such system in many contexts.

Comment: If this is the pronunciation of a dictionary this old-fashioned and imprecise notation is explained in the introductory pages of the dictionary. Dictionary. com gives the pronunciation in this old-fashioned way of American dictionaries, but also in IPA-system. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/analgesic?s=t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pronunciation respelling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling

> A pronunciation respelling is a regular phonetic respelling of a word that does have a standard spelling, so as to indicate the pronunciation. Pronunciation respellings are sometimes seen in dictionaries.

Specifically, your example is a *non-phonemic pronunciation system*. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English))

Comment: Right. And that means it's not the only way to spell it, and that it likely won't be understood by some (maybe most) people, depending on their dialect and how they tend to pronounce and read things. Not a useful system.